# Wagtail - is there a simple way of checking programmatically if a user has Wagtail admin access?

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I would like to be able to check in my code whether a user has access to the Wagtail admin interface. I was imagining a field on the Django model like `user.is_wagtail_user`.

Is there an existing way to do this? Or is there something simple I can add?

Answer (score 1):

Access to the Wagtail admin is controlled by the standard Django permission system, with a permission named `wagtailadmin.access_admin`. This can be checked with the [`has_perm` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm):

`user.has_perm('wagtailadmin.access_admin')`